GEE, Error generating chart of AEROSOL: User memory limit exceeded
I want to make a ui.Chart of aerosol with MODIS, Optical_Depth_047.

The Error generating chart: User memory limit exceeded, has been
occurred.

I couldn't find anyway to solve it. Could anyone give me an advice?
Here's my script:
//Date Llist
var dateList = [
   {start: ee.Date('2017-01-01'), end: ee.Date('2018-12-31')}, //Duration1
   {start: ee.Date('2017-10-01'), end: ee.Date('2017-12-31')}, //Duration2
   {start: ee.Date('2018-01-01'), end: ee.Date('2018-03-31')}, //Duration3
   ];

//var aoi = geometry.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_NAME','Ningde'));
//var aoi = geometry.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_NAME','Kuala Lumpur'));

//Move the map to AoI
Map.centerObject(aoi2, 6)

//Select band data 
var dust = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/061/MCD19A2_GRANULES')
             .select('Optical_Depth_047')
             .filterBounds(aoi2)
             .filterDate(dateList[0].start,dateList[0].end);

//Filter data by date and mean the value           
var dust1 = dust.filter(ee.Filter.date(dateList[1].start, dateList[1].end));
var dust1_mean = dust1.mean();
var dust2 = dust.filter(ee.Filter.date(dateList[2].start, dateList[2].end));
var dust2_mean = dust2.mean();

//Band visualization parameter
var band_viz = {
  min: 0,
  max: 1100,
  palette: ['black', 'blue', 'purple', 'cyan', 'green', 'yellow', 'red']
};

//Add layer
Map.addLayer(dust1_mean.clip(aoi2), band_viz, '2017_FourthQuarter');
Map.addLayer(dust2_mean.clip(aoi2), band_viz, '2018_FisrtQuarter');

//Add chart
var chart = ui.Chart.image
                .doySeriesByYear({
                  imageCollection: dust,
                  bandName: 'Optical_Depth_047',
                  region: aoi2,
                  regionReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                  scale:1000, //Resolution of original data is 1km. The unit for the scale is 'meter'
                  sameDayReducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
                  startDay: 1,
                  endDay: 365
                })
                .setOptions({
                  title: 'Trend of Malaysia',
                  hAxis: {
                    title: 'Date',
                    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
                  },
                  vAxis: {
                    title: 'Value',
                    titleTextStyle: {italic: false, bold: true}
                  },
                  lineWidth: 2,
                  pointSize: 3,
                  interpolateNulls: true,
                });
          
//Print chart
print(chart);

